# gedit snippets plugin not working for encodings other than UTF-8

Tags: gedit, plugins

I just ran into a problem with the snippets plugin of gedit 3.4.1 running on Ubuntu 12.04.  The problem is that the snippets plugin stops working (i. e., doesn't react to keyboard shortcuts and tab-completion) when a file has an encoding other than UTF-8, e. g. ISO-8859-1.  In that case, the snippets plugin doesn't work any more and the error output on the console states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/library.py", line 678, in accelerator_activated
    ret = cb(group, obj, keyval, mod)
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/windowactivatable.py", line 216, in accelerator_activated
    return controller.accelerator_activate(keyval, mod)
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 148, in accelerator_activate
    self.apply_snippet(snippets[0])
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 519, in apply_snippet
    env = self.get_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 483, in get_environment
    v = variables[var](buf)
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 348, in env_get_current_line
    return {'utf8': u8, 'noenc': self.string_in_native_doc_encoding(buf, u8)}
  File "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 320, in string_in_native_doc_encoding
    except GLib.GError:
NameError: global name 'GLib' is not defined
```

Apparently, there is a problem in file /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py where a function GLib.convert is called whenever the document encoding is not UTF-8.  Consequently, if I save the same file as UTF-8, it all works well.

I'm not much into Python, so any pointer how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this bug is about to be fixed in one of the next versions of Ubuntu.  For an immediate fix, simply edit `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py`, changing line 22 from

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Gio, GtkSource, Gedit
```

to

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Gio, GLib, GtkSource, Gedit
```

(i. e., include the `GLib` import).
Don't forget to relaunch gedit :-)